# Is there a way to create a URL (new WP page) that can only be accessed from a specific source?

Tags: pages, urls, security

To explain further, here's what I"m looking to do:

1. Create a WP page
2. Use the URL and implement it in a reader service that is hosted (not downloadable) that in order to read (& access the URL) you would have needed to purchase a subscription.
3. Allow only visitors coming in from the guide access to the page (would be invisible if user clicked on it and tried accessing it from a different location)

To simplify this explanation, I'm looking for a way to only give access to a specific URL from a specific URL.

What would be the best route to take? Are there any plugins that could accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by "reader service"? Do you mean RSS feed? Would this work?: http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/pay-per-view/

Comment: Not quite, more along the lines of interactive courses / guides where at the end, a reward would be available via the link (why having the page invisible to everyone else is important)

Comment: Are the users taking the course authenticated? Hmm, you could add a flag (AKA user_meta http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) to their account, and then add some logic to the template to restrict views. This option is a little more secure than just basing access on the URL. Not sure this answer helps much.

Answer (score 2):

Only way to base access on url users come from is to rely on $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], but as [official php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) says:

> Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

One chance is to use a secret key and pass it as variable in the url, then in the template check it against a custom field, something like:

```
if ( $_GET['secretkey'] == get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'secretkey', true) ) {
   // show the post
} else {
   echo 'Nothing for you here.';
}
```

but everyone knows the key (and add it to the url) will see the post (wherever comes from), so is not really secure.